# multiple search criteria asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am writing to seek help on implementing a multiple criteria search function in asp.net webform.
I am novice user of asp.net and implemented the following vb code using an sample C# code but I can not get it to display any output.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

**aspx**

```
 <div class = "hideSkiplink">
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Cusip/Isin" ForeColor="White">         </asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick = "btnSearch_Click" />
  </div>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bwic testConnectionString %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [Deal_name], [Cusip], [Isin], [Original_size], [Price],_
       [Price_recieved], [Deal_type], [Price_type], [Date] FROM [Price]">   </asp:SqlDataSource>
     <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

     </div>
```

**aspx.vb**

```
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Web.Services
 Imports System.Configuration
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient


 Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from Price where Deal_name like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' or Cusip and Isin like '%" + TextBox2.Text + "%'"
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind()


 End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to be doing an or on both `Cusip` and `Isin` separately:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = _
"SELECT * FROM Price " + _
"WHERE Deal_name like '%" + TextBox1.Text + _
      "%' AND (Cusip like '%" + TextBox2.Text + 
      "%' OR  Isin like '%" + TextBox2.Text + "%')"
```

This will select records where the `Deal_name` matches `TextBox1` and `Cusip` or `Isin` matches `TextBox2`. If this is not what you are after, please clarify.

EDIT:

Your `GridView` requires a `DataSourceID` to be set on it, otherwise it doesn't know where it's data is coming from. Take a look at the example below [taken from here](http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/bind-gridview-sqldatasource-control.html), which doesn't require a button click to do the binding.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$Connectionstrings:ERPConnectionString%>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM AccountsTable">
</asp:SqlDataSource>  
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
     AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Dear @Tanner, Thank you so much response and help.  my current issue is, when I type in the search criteria (txtbox) and press enter, nothing is displayed as output. I can not figure out why. any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Would I have to compute more behind in order to compute gridview with search criteria. If so, what functions I need to implement?

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanner, for your time and help in solving this issue.  I really appreciate your help and support.  I got the webform to work from your gridview control parameters and thank you for the useful link. Have a great day/evening.